# "Squeezing out of a dead man" proverb

Tags: proverbs

There is a proverb with meaning "although the resource is almost empty, we still try to get something from it, regardless of that our attempts are most likely meaningless". I recall that I've heard a saying "squeezing out of a dead man" in this case, but now this sounds a bit weird and I can't google any examples.

Is there any proverb which can be identified by my explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for ***"[you can't squeeze blood from a turnip](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/you-can-t-squeeze-blood-from-a-turnip)"***:

> - You can only get from people what they are willing or able to give.

Dictionary.com

Comment: I haven't heard it before but it sounds good. May I use it as "Doing smth is actually squeezing blood from a turnip"?

Comment: @IvanSmirnov - yes you can.

Comment: The very similar "can't get blood from a stone" is also common.

Answer (score 3):

While it's not exactly a proverb, I'd like to mention the verbal construct “***to squeeze the last [resource] from [source]***” (occasionally with *out of* instead of *from*). The resource is given in its smallest denomination possible; e.g., drops if the resource is a liquid, cents or pennies if it is money.

Examples:

- The taxpayer was squeezing the last cents from the poor.
- We squeezed the last bit of information from the book.
- I tried to squeeze the last drop of water from the towel.